# Angular Reactive Forms and"submit" buttons

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm building a reactive form with Angular, I have obviously a type "submit" button.
I have also other buttons elements . But I don't want these buttons to submit the form. How can I achieve that ?
I thought without "type='submit'" attribute on button elements, the form wasn't submitted, but it seems not to be the case.

Thanks

Comment: `type="button"`

Comment: ok thanks, very easy. So most browsers without "type" attribute on buttons elements add "type=submit" by default, correct ?

Comment: If your button is inside a form tag, it will by default be of type `submit` unless you explicitly tell it to be of type `button` :)

Comment: Can you share your code

Answer (score 8):

Submit button should be of type submit, and every other button that is not used to submit should be type button.

`<button type="submit">This is for Submit</button>`
`<button type="button">Regular Degular button</button>`

Comment: All buttons seem to do submit for me whether they are or not of type submit

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to do this as:

```
type ="button"
```